# Push datas in existing array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

I have an array:

```
var array = [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

I need to push datas from an another array to obtain this result :

```
[7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(../sun.png)'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

Could someone explain me what the array_push equivalent to obtain this result?

Thanks for support

Comment: There is array_name.push() function in javascript. try this.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for you help.  In my example, i need replace a value (26.5 ) by an another array and add some informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function may help you:

```
function replaceItem (array, item, newItem) {
   for(var index in array) {
      if(array[index]==item) {
          array.splice(index, 1, newItem);
      }
   }
}
```

no you just need to call you functio like this :

```
replaceItem(array, 25.2, { y: 26.5, marker: { symbol: 'url(../sun.png)' } });
```

notice the function doesn't return anything, it replaces directly on the array because in javascript an array is passed by its reference.

now let me explain to you how all the array insertion functions work on javascript :

---

**Array.prototype.push:**

this one adds an item at the end of the array :

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.push(4); // a ==> [1,2,3,4]
```

the opposite is, `Array.prototype.pop`

```
var lastItem = a.pop();
// lastItem == 4
// a ==> [1,2,3]
```

---

**Array.prototype.unshift:**

this one adds an element at the beginning of an array :

```
a = [1,2,3];
a.unshif(0); // a ==> [0,1,2,3]
```

the opposite is `Array.prototype.shift`

```
var firstItem = a.shift();
// firstItem == 0
// a ==> [1,2,3]
```

---

**Array.prototype.splice**

this one removes some items, and replace them with new items given as arguments. The arguments are : `( startingIndex, numberOfItemsToReplace, [, newItems ])` and it returns the items removed from the array

```
a = [1,2,3];
removedItems = a.splice(0,2,3,3,3);
// removedItems ==> [1, 2]
// a ==> [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
array.splice(array.indexOf(26.5),1,{y: 26.5,marker: {symbol: 'url(../sun.png)'}});
```

It finds the position of `26.5` and replace it with the object you want.

Comment: IMHO most efficient solution

Answer (score 2):

are you searching for a code like this?

```
var a=[7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6];
    var b={y: 26.5,
    marker: {
        symbol: 'url(../sun.png)'
    }};
    a.splice(7,1,b);

    alert(a.toSource());
```

The splice(*index*, *howmanytoremove*,*item*) adds your item at index, removing *howmanytoremove*

Answer (score 1):

```
array.push(5);
```

array is an object. so just use its method push()

If you want to insert it, use the slice() - method:

```
var value= "whatever";
var insertIndex = 3;
array.slice(insertIndex, 0, value);
```

Comment: Hello Alexis. Thks for your reply.  By using array.push(), a new value is added at the end of my object.  In my example, i need replace a value (26.5 ) by an another array and add some informations

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var data = [78, 89, 89, 346];
var obj = {
  'name': 'Gholi'
};

data.push(obj);

console.log(data);
```